# Javascript/CSS/HTML - How can I write superscript as a value in a <input type=“button”/>?

Tags: html, css

How can I write superscript  in an input.

Comment: One acronym for you: [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: An easy way is to copy and paste this character (U+00B2): ²

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of text.

Comment: Please don't post a question if you are not willing to explain your problem. This platform is not for people lie you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `button` tag instead of `input`

```html
<button type="button">x<sup>2</sup></button>
```